# Is it possible to have a pool of splitters on a camel route

Tags: apache-camel

I'm using a Splitter to break up a large file, do some processing on the splits and then, with a custom AggregationStrategy, save the updated splits to a new file. The splitter is configured for streaming but not parallel processing. This works fine.

The problem is that the Splitter calls doAggregate (inherited from MulticastProcessor) which is synchronized. When there are concurrent requests on that route, the performance is significantly impacted by the synchronization. Obviously, the more concurrent requests, the worse it is.

Is there a way to create a pool of splitter instances that can be used for the route? Each incoming exchange could use a different splitter instance and thus avoid the synchronized doAggregate call. Is it possible to leverage a custom ProcessorFactory to do this?

Update:

I created a simple test to demonstrate what I'm talking about.
I have a route like this

```
from("direct:splitterTest").split(method(new MySplitter(), "rowIterator"), new MyAggregationStrategy()).to("log:someSplitProcessing?groupSize=500")
```

The MySplitter simply returns an iterator of 10000 String[] which emulates reading a file.

The MyAggregationStrategy pretends to perform some work and saves the records to a new file.
In my test, I added loop to emulate some processing like

```
Random random = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
    random.nextGaussian();
}
```

I submit requests to the route like this (not that I'm not passing in a file in this case because the splitter is just returning dummy data):

```
ProducerTemplate producerTemplate = camelContext.createProducerTemplate();
Future<File> future1 = producerTemplate.asyncRequestBody("direct:splitterTest", null, File.class);
Future<File> future2 = producerTemplate.asyncRequestBody("direct:splitterTest", null, File.class);
System.out.println(future1.get());
System.out.println(future2.get());
```

I wanted to post visualvm screenshots showing how 2 and 4 concurrent in-flight exchanges are impacted by the synchronization but this account is too new to be allowed to post images.

The point is this. When the route is created, there is a single Splitter instance for that route. Multiple in-flight exchanges on that route will synchronize in the doAggregate call which seriously impacts the processing time for each request. When there are 4 requests, you can see that 3 threads are blocked while one is in the doAggregate call.

Due to the nature of the processing that I'm doing, I'm not able to configure the splitter to process in parallel so what I'm looking for is a way to create multiple splitter instances. I could create, say, 4 copies of the route and then use a routingSlip or dynamicRouter to round robin requests to each but that seems kind of ugly and I am hoping there's a better way.

Comment: Are you controlling your thread pools on the splitter? Please post some code. I had a similar problems but by using thread pools I was able to limit the number of threads and thus optimize the running of the splitters.

Comment: I'm not using a thread pool in the splitter (per se) because it's not running parallel (I need to process the rows in order so parallel isn't a good option for me). The submissions to the route, however, are using async calls through a producer template with a thread pool and the requests are running on those threads. The issue, though, is that when the route is defined, a single Splitter instance is created. All doAggregate calls (even though they may be running on different threads for different files) are synchronized.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use your own thread pool to save in parallel if you want from the doAggregate.

Comment: For a single file, I need to process the rows in order which is why the route is not configured for parallel. The ProducerTemplate, though has a thread pool and multiple requests are run concurrently on the route. The actual splitting and invocation of the processors run concurrently across multiple cores without issue until it hits the doAggregate call.